# Scrollable TextView in Android Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, textview, scrollable, android-appwidget

I would like to create an android widget with a scrollable textview.

The solutions given to this question 
[Making TextView scrollable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)
cannot be applied because it is a widget:

1.
This

```
 findViewById(R.id.textview).setMovementMethod(new MovementMethod());
```

does not work, since `findViewById` is not available in `AppWidgetProvider` but only in `Activity`.

2.Putting a `ScrollView` around the `TextView` also does not work, because I get an 
`InflateException`:

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class ScrollView
```

Can anybody give me a hint, how to make a `TextView` in a Widget scrollable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible.

More on this can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9580

and here:
[How to make a scrollable app widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922114/how-to-make-a-scrollable-app-widget)

So, probably it is possible to do make appwidgets scrollable in the HTC sense environment but not for normal android environments.

A way around this is to add buttons that go up and down in a list.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by putting the text view inside ListView with single node, which is supported in App widget.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections

Comment: How exactly does the xml need to be formatted?

Comment: This is the only solution!


Now "not possible" reply is marked as solution - it's wrong!

p.s.
Another "solution" is: add to textview any web link - for example: www.google.com
After that vertical scrollbar is appeared. But it's not elegant and full solution. It's temporary workaround maybe...

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this with two buttons which increment and decrement through an array. Just having trouble accessing the global variables. Did you make any headway on this?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

- Add to textview any web link - for example: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).
- Setting text value with HtmlCompat.fromHtml method:

  textView.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml("some text" + "\nwww.google.com", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));

After that vertical scrollbar is appeared.
But it's not elegant and full solution. It's temporary workaround maybe...

The complete full solutiion is **bat-el-g** 's answer - with adding ListView.

Current marked solution (which just tell: "it's not possible") - is wrong.

Answer (score -4):

In mainactivity.java:

after code text view:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView id);
```

Enter this code:

```
txt.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

and you will be ok.