# Android widget vertical scroll for Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, android-widget, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to figure out how to enable vertical scroll for an Android widget.
From what I read in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243161/problem-with-using-scrollview-in-a-homepage-widget)  it's possible to do that only from Android version 3.0 and up.
However, I saw a phone (Motorola Razr) with Android version 2.3.6 that had a Gmail widget with a vertical scroll.
So I can't understand if it's possible or not? And if it is possible, how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Manufacturers generally build out Android from a custom version of AOSP. Since the entire source for Android 2.3.x is available, it is quite possible that Motorola simply added support for scrolling widgets by modifying the source for their own devices (potentially using the same techniques that AOSP 3.0 does). And if this is indeed the case, that will require changes in the underlying operating system and hence will likely not be available to you if you are building the widgets using the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If by widgets you are talking about ? extends widget.View, you can always build you own View that does vertical scrolling.

This envolves parsing onTouchEvent (and probably onDispatchTouchEvent) and a lot of math.

I did it myself at work.