# Android Widget Scrollabe Textview

Tags: android, android-widget

i'm developing a SMS Widget.So came to across [messages-widget](http://code.google.com/p/messages-widget/)

When i tried to replicate, the scroll feature is not available to that widget.

when i surfed, results where `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879748/scrollable-textview-in-android-widget`

Note i'm using Android 2.2 API Level 8.

Can anyone tell me how textview is scrollable with that opensource coding.

Is it possible to make a scrollable textview in widget ?

Comment: try to put your textview in scrollview.

Comment: scrollview is not supported with widgets in API level 8

Comment: simple! create a link to see full conversation.

Comment: Sorry @Gandarez i couldn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is not a scrollable widget. It has buttons to move to the next/previous message.

HTC (and maybe others) have scrollable widgets, but it's their own implementation.

Scrollable widgets (with ListView and GridView) are available in Android 3.0+ (API 11+).