# Cannot make widgets scrollable

Tags: android, layout, widget, scrollview, imagebutton

I want to create a list of image buttons and i added 3 of them but only two are visible and i want to make them scrollable. I tried using ScrollView but it still doesnt work. I also tried replacing RelativeLayout in the first line with ScrollView but the app started to crash.

Here's the xml file:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back"
tools:context=".home">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/download"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="230dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/geo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4300dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/images"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a scrollable app widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922114/how-to-make-a-scrollable-app-widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the width and height of first scroll view as wrap content .If it doesn't work then
Make only a single scroll view.Then make a Linear layout as its child and in linear layout having vertical orientation add your 3 image buttons.